# Javascript TRUE is not defined or in quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a XML file that contains

```
<car>
    <id>123</id>
    <sunroof>FALSE</sunroof>
    <service>TRUE</service>
</car>
```

The following code only works if I wrap TRUE inside quotes e.g `(service == "TRUE")`

```
var service = tis.find("service").text();

if(service === TRUE){
    var service_tag = '<a title="Service" href="">Service</a>'
} else {
    var service_tag = '';
}
```

Comment: Boolean true is different from string `"TRUE"`, works as designed

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Without quotes javascript will try to interpret `TRUE` as a value / expression.  There is no value `TRUE` natively defined in javascript.  There is `true` but javascript is case sensitive so it won't bind `TRUE` to `true`.

The value you get back from `text()` is a `string` primitive.  Writing `"TRUE"` gives you back the `string` `"TRUE"` which does compare succesfully with the value `service`

Answer (score 9):

JavaScript boolean `true` and `false` are lower case.

Answer (score 3):

Set service equal to this, so JavaScript will be able to interpret your values:

```
var service = tis.find("service").text().toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 1):

its because the tripe equal also check for type, and TRUE it's a identifier "TRUE" is a value

```
// this will work
if(service === "TRUE"){
    var service_tag = '<a title="Service" href="">Service</a>'
} else {
    var service_tag = '';
}
```

[Difference between == and === in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523643/difference-between-and-in-javascript)

Comment: ha, this is not what he/she was asking, the real issue was miss spelling, its `true` not `True`

Answer (score 1):

This is expected.

`tis.find("service").text();` returns a string, not a boolean, and the JavaScript boolean for truth is `true` (which is case sensitive, like everything else in the language).

Answer (score 1):

```
var service = tis.find("service").text();
```

This returns a string "TRUE".
Since === checks for the type as well, it always returns false.

Answer (score 1):

`TRUE` refers to a variable named `TRUE` which doesn't exist, so you get an error. `"TRUE"` is a string containing the characters `TRUE`. Your variable `service` will contain a string, so the second of these are what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error because I quickly typed it with typo

```
someBooleanVar === ture
```

this is wrong

it should be `true` not ture